# 3 moderators to approve comment

Tags: comments, moderation

Guys, I need to know how to do the following:

When I receive a comment ...
This comment must be approved by three moderators.
To appear on the site.

Anyone know how to do it or some plugin?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can use `comment_unapproved_to_approved` action hook to call your function which will use a commentmeta field to count how many times that comment has been approved or by how many users and if it's less then 3 then we updated the comment to not approved :

### update

I'm posting an updated code in the form of a plugin which fixes a few typos:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: 3-comment-mod
Plugin URI: http://en.bainternet.info
Description: Answer to http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/15574/3-moderators-to-approve-comment/15595#15595
Version: 1.0
Author: Bainternet
Author URI: http://en.bainternet.info
*/

if(!function_exists('check_add_approved_count')) {

    function check_add_approved_count($comment){
        global $current_user;
        get_currentuserinfo();
        //respect the admin comments approved by one approval
        if (current_user_can('manage_options')){
            return '';
        }
        $mods = get_comment_meta($comment->comment_ID,'approved_by',true);
        if(!empty($mods) && is_array($mods)){

            //only allow each mod to approve once
            if (in_array($current_user->ID,$mods)){
                return '';
            }else{

                //here we check the count
                if (count($mods) < 3){
                    //if less then 3 then
                    //we add the current mod to the approving list 

                    $mods[] = $current_user->ID;
                    update_comment_meta($comment->comment_ID,'approved_by',$mods);

                    //and revert back the comment to not approved
                    $commentarr = get_comment($comment->comment_ID, ARRAY_A);
                    $commentarr['comment_approved'] = 0; 
                    wp_update_comment($commentarr);
                }
            }
        }
        //if we got here it means that this is the first approval 
        //so we just add the user to the list and revert back the comment to not approved
        $mods[] = $current_user->ID;
        update_comment_meta($comment->comment_ID,'approved_by',$mods);

        //and revert back the comment to not approved
        $commentarr = get_comment($comment->comment_ID, ARRAY_A);
        $commentarr['comment_approved'] = 0; 
        wp_update_comment($commentarr);
    }
}

add_action('comment_unapproved_to_approved','check_add_approved_count');


?>
```

Comment: thanks for the feedback 

We have three owners in the specific site 
The comment must be approved by each of them.

Comment: this code a moderator can approve more than once to comment?
the idea is each of the three, only able to approve a time
with 3, the commentary is released

Comment: Nope, a mod can only approve once each comments and its checked with `/only allow each mod to approve once
        if (in_array($current_user->ID,$mods)){
            return '';`

Comment: ok i will test and tell you about it.

Comment: Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'check_add_approved_count' not found or invalid function name in /home/sitename/wp-includes/plugin.php on line 395 , i add your function in Theme Functions (functions.php)

Comment: change the functions name from `add_approved_count` to `check_add_approved_count` or use this tested working plugin http://pastebin.com/SzifeZpr

Comment: ok i will try, thanks a lot again, tomorrow i tell you about my test.

Comment: Hello, I installed the plugin. 
which the hierarchical level to have the 3 approvals? 
Approved it as admin , With one approval, was released.

Comment: look at the code it says `respect the admin comments approved by one approval` ...

Comment: ok i try approve a comment ,  3 editors users approve.

Comment: The comment still not approved. which User Type need to adopt three times?

Comment: Anyone who can mange-comments

Comment: in the third approval, I get this error:

Warning: is_array () expects parameter 1 Exactly, Given 0 in / moderators to home/site/public_html/site/wp-content/plugins/plugin-name/index.php on line 21
1304457802

Comment: change `if(!empty($mods) && is_array()){` with  `if(!empty($mods) && is_array($mods)){`

Comment: Now yes, tested and working perfectly! 

Just one detail ... 
Each time a moderator to approve the comment, in this case three times, the post author receives e-mail alerts of 3 comments (but are 3 passes) 

Any suggestions to organize this?

Comment: i got this new error when second moderator approve a new comment: Fatal error: Function name must be a string in /home/sites/public_html/site/wp-content/plugins/plugin/index.php on line 29

Comment: Paste the exact code you are using

Comment: Code: http://www.cargoesclub.com/plugin.txt

Comment: use the updated code in the answer

Comment: Currently the script works, however we have a problem...
I have three editors, the comment must be approved by three editors....
with only two approvals the comments are being approved...
I tried to modify the code of 3 to 4 and not forward...
I am using the latest version of wordpress...

Comment: @Alyson: Works fine last i check, the only thing i can think of is that if one of the users is an admin then the comment is approved automatically.

Comment: I created 3 users, I put them as editors. Do you check it with last Wordpress?

Comment: just tested it with a fresh install of 3.2.1 and 3.3 works fine.

Comment: I am using the plugin Thoughtful Comments
for administration of comments by the front end
you can test your plugin with this?

I am investigating why be released here in the second approval

Comment: well it could have something to do with your front end approval code create a pastebin of it and I'll take a look

Comment: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/thoughtful-comments/

Comment: i see this error when i try approve the second time some comment via admin panel: Fatal error: Function name must be a string in /wp-content/plugins/3 moderators to approve zomments/index.php on line 29

Comment: Any news about this error  Bainternet ?